# How to make a release build in VS express 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

How do I make a release build in visual studio express 2010 (VB) ?

Comment: Isn't it just changing the drop-down from "Debug" to "Release" and then running the build again?

Comment: +1 for answering, but. which drop down would that be?

Comment: Beware that release build corrupts the application. As things are you are forced to publush debug builds. Stupid, I know, but that is microsoft for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load a project.  Then the drop-down will appear on the standard toolbar.

Comment: +1 and the answer ... D'oh!   I can't believe that I missed that.

Answer (score 4):

I've noticed that it is hard to change active build configuration in VS Express.

Changing the **Tools->Settings->Expert Settings** allows to access **Build->Configuration Manager**.